# Can't have content on the same row with an image

Tags: html, wordpress, image

Whenever I add two or more images one after the other, instead of displaying all of them on the same row as is normal, my new WordPress theme pushes them to a new row. I've found that if I just align each of them to the left, it displays them on the same row, but that's not really a solution, it's a workaround (+ I've got old posts where this would work as normal and I can't go back and edit all of them).

Example:

```
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-7" src="http://temp.ovidiuav.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Image-placeholder-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" />text<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-6" src="http://temp.ovidiuav.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/generic-image-placeholder-150x150.png" alt="" width="150" height="150" />
```

I've got an image, some text, and another image, that should just display one after the other, on the same row. Instead, they're each on their own row. So even if the content is after an image or before an image, it just can't be on the same row as the image itself.

To sum up: I can't add anything before or after an image, on the same row, unless I align the image to the left. I think that's a concise explanation of the issue. I just want my theme to stop this behavior and I can't figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The image is likely shown with `display: block`, you probably want to use `display: inline-block`

Comment: You have to edit your theme specific style sheet to achieve this. Show us some specific code or example to help you

Comment: @DBS You're right, that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBS found the solution (first comment on the question):

> The image is likely shown with display: block, you probably want to use display: inline-block